# Confused about the differences of AdMob, Ad Exchange & DFP

Tags: android, admob, adsense

I read through [Google Mobile Ads SDK document](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/) online . There, it provides the guidance of how to use AdMob , Ad Exchange & DoubleClick for Publisher(DFP).

But, after read those guidance, I am really get confused about the differences among them. I feel they are almost the same for my mobile Android app. Could someone please make me clear about the most primary differences among these three?

Answer (score 7):

As long as I know, there is one SDK, and 3 different ways to get ads.

AdMob manages investors for you and you get paid for views and clicks.
DFP gives you a container for ads, but you have to find companies that pay for them.
Ad Exchange (I'm not sure) lets you trade your ads for others'.

Answer (score 2):

As reference for future visitors:

1. DFP is a platform that allows publishers to sell space in their digital properties (meaning websites, apps, etc, also called *inventory*) via a 1:1 arranged sell where the advertiser has to send over the creatives to the publisher. More details [here](https://support.google.com/dfp_premium/answer/6022000?hl=en).
2. AdX allows publishers to sell their inventory to buyers in a programmatic auction. More info on [how this auction works](https://support.google.com/adxseller/answer/152039?hl=en&ref_topic=2904831).
3. AdMob is similar to AdX, but focused solely on the mobile in-app advertising environment. Useful [Help Center article](https://support.google.com/admob/answer/6168758?hl=en&ref_topic=7579127).

Comment: Does that mean that if you already have Adx running for in-app inventory that you don't need AdMob as well?

Comment: Exactly. AdX demand includes the one of AdMob, so using one of them should suffice. In terms of implementation, they both use the same SDK.