# What is the difference between Admob ads, and "Double Click" ads?

Tags: android, admob, double-click-advertising

### Background

Recently I've noticed there are 2 samples for Admob ads ([**here**](https://github.com/googleads/googleads-mobile-android-examples)):

- Admob
- Double Click

### The problem

I'd like to just know what is "Double Click".

Reading over the Internet, to me it seems just like a different ads-company that Google has purchased, but I want to understand more.

### What I've tried

When I asked about it, I got [**this answer**](https://github.com/googleads/googleads-mobile-android-examples/issues/125#issuecomment-397728207):

> The Google Mobile Ads SDK supports 2 Google ad products: AdMob and
>   [**DoubleClick for Publishers**](https://www.google.com/intl/en/doubleclick/publishers/welcome/) (DFP). DFP has a docset [**here**](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/dfp/android/quick-start) that is
>   similar to AdMob's. This GitHub repo hosts examples for both AdMob and
>   DFP.
>
> I'm assuming you're using AdMob, in which case I recommend sticking to
>   the [**AdMob docset**](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/quick-start) and using the AdMob examples.

But this made me even more confused.

### Questions

1. What is exactly "Double Click" ? Is it a full alternative to Admob?  Does it provide something else? Something better?
2. What are "DFP" and "docset" ? How are they related to Admob and "Double Click" ?

Comment: Don't think this is a 'programming' question. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24649222/confused-about-the-differences-of-admob-ad-exchange-dfp

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a question about ad networks and their offerings, not computer programming.

Comment: That's too bad that you think this way. I thought that maybe it's related to having a different SDK, because there were 2 different samples, without explanation of what is each. Just because you know the answer to the question, doesn't mean all know it. There are already similar questions like Admob vs Firebase SDKs, which weren't marked to be closed, but even got upvotes. Example: https://stackoverflow.com/q/37322451/878126 . I don't see how different this one is from there. It's related to programming the same way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DoubleClick is a subsidiary of Google which develops and provides Internet ad serving services. Its clients include agencies, marketers and publishers who serve businesses like Microsoft, General Motors, Coca-Cola, Motorola, L'Oréal, Palm, Apple, Visa, Nike, and Carlsberg among others.

DoubleClick was founded in 1996 by Kevin O'Connor and Dwight Merriman and have headquarters in New York City, United States.

It was formerly listed as "DCLK" on the NASDAQ, and was purchased by private equity firms Hellman & Friedman and JMI Equity in July 2005. In March 2008, Google acquired DoubleClick for US$3.1 billion.

so it's simply just another ad company, no difference at all and i recommend sticking with admob since it has a lot more popularity than DoubleClick

Comment: I see. So it's just another ad network. Thank you. Wonder why Google doesn't just merge them under the same SDK and make them work together.