# Goodle Ad Manager SDK vs AdMob SDK

Tags: android, admob, google-ad-manager

Ad Manager and AdMob both refer to integrating the *Google Mobile Ads SDK* into your app. But is it the same SDK, or different ones?

From [Ad Manager quick start](https://developers.google.com/ad-manager/mobile-ads-sdk/android/quick-start)

> Integrating the Google Mobile Ads SDK into an app is the first step toward displaying ads and earning revenue.

From [AdMob quick start](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/quick-start)

> Integrating the Google Mobile Ads SDK into an app is the first step toward displaying ads and earning revenue.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24649222/confused-about-the-differences-of-admob-ad-exchange-dfp) might help you to understand the differences (knowing Ad Manager is the new name of DFP) : same SDK, different implementations for different goals.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

They are the same SDK. Their implementations are slightly different because they would connect to two different ads management platforms.

AdMob is Google's automatic ad exchange for Mobile Apps.  Google Ad Manager can manage ad exchange from both mobile apps and web pages, and Ad Manager also manages direct-sold ads and private deals.

You can choose how to implement the SDK based on what ads management platform you are using.

Comment: Is it possible to use both Admob and AdManager ads into a single app? For eg: Use one screen for Admob and another for Ad Manager.

Comment: @bhaskar AdManager is basically AdMob mediation platform but for both mobile and desktop